# PHP: Getting child elements from each HTML list entry

Tags: php, domxpath

I'm using PHP to search through a HTML source file to gather list (li) elements, and I need to get multiple anchor links from within each list entry (i.e. each list entry has a bunch of information including links). I had been using DOMXPath and "query" to get the list elements; but then I need to run the result through another query but of course the result is in the wrong format. Here are the relevant sections of code (with the rest left out for brevity and replaced with "..."):

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
....
// first get all (UL) lists of class "mw-contributions-list"
$ULList = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='mw-contributions-list']");
// then loop thru these
for ($UL = 0; $UL < $ULList->length; $UL++) 
{
    //get all (li) elements (they don't have a class)
    $LIList = $ULList->item($UL)->getElementsByTagName("li");
    // then loop thru these LI elements
    for ($LI = 0; $LI < $LIList->length; $LI++) 
    {
        ....
        (at this point I need to do an XPath query on $LIList->item($LI) 
        but after converting it to the correct format.  
        How do I do that? )
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `$xpath->query("//ul[@class='mw-contributions-list']/li//a")` to get the anchors directly?

Comment: Some of the list entries have only one anchor whereas some have two, so I need to process each (li) element separately and then gather the information from each.

Comment: The above xpath should still work in that scenario. Is there other information you need to capture from the `li` elements? It would be helpful to have some sample data and the output you would like to get from that.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Good to hear. If you think your solution might have value to other users, you can always post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: One lingering problem: if I use the code to process a large number of pages in a single session, I get the message :  "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.  Please try again later.  716a0f91ec458a289d983954a125468a 2422ee66a36d9db73dd4bc60badd3483 a8c88487960d0c188267cb72415b9130  "
Any idea why this occurs ?

Comment: Never seen a message like that. It might be related to the load on your server, but I really couldn't  be sure.